# How to fadeIn text within a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html, fade

I know the simple answer to this is to do the following:

```
$('#div > p').fadeIn()
```

Although in my specific case, that doesn't seem to work. I use a lot of the same IDs on my webpage, and basically I would have to use `>` twice, and that doesn't seem to work.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p4sA3/2/

Basically, I only want the text from the #information div to fadeOut and fadeIn the new text from the other div-wrap.

How would I achieve this?

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#goodbye-wrap').hide();

$('#change').click(function(){

    $('#hello-wrap').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $('#goodbye-wrap').fadeIn(600);
    });

});
```

Comment: you shouldn't use the same id for different elements

Comment: What if I used class instead, would it make a difference? I think I would still experience problems.

Comment: @BradleyMitchell , look an element can have more than one class and multiple elements can have the same class .. but an element cant have more than one id , and two elements MUST NOT have the same id ..
this is the worst bad practice . so use classes instead

Comment: @BradleyMitchell, are you allowed to change the html structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you shouldn't use the same id for different elements. Having said that, you can always use `.first()` for example, to filter previous selections

check out: http://api.jquery.com/first/

also, like `.first()` you have other filters like `.last()` or `.eq()`

EDIT: I'm getting closer to what you want now? http://jsfiddle.net/p4sA3/3/

Comment: Doesn't seem to accomplish what I want. I don't want the yellow boxes to disappear. I just want the text on both of them to fadeOut with the old and fadeIn with the new. I've been working with .eq(), but I haven't got it to work yet.

Comment: the just wrap the text in `<span>` and give it a class name and hide it , or show it

Comment: Yes, but the difficulty I have is doing it with both of them simultaneously (or with multiple boxes for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be using the same ID for multiple elements. The whole point of them is to provide a *unique* identifier for an element. If you find yourself using the same ID multiple times, it should be a class. With properly categorized elements, you should be able to use CSS's selectors effectively.

That said, you'll still have problems. You can't make the previous text disappear without fading the entire block out, so I think you'll have to try another approach. Nesting the new text inside the original div would make it easier.

If that isn't an option (though, it really should be!), you might try fading the Hello text to yellow, hiding the hello div fast and switching in the the good-bye div, and then fading the goodbye text to black. Definitely a hack, but sometimes that's necessary.

See animate() for color fading. http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Comment: Okay, I fixed it and updated the JSFiddle, but I still need to fix my original problem.

Comment: See the edit. Multiple #'s provoke a real strong knee jerk reaction... but your question is legit.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely simple if you first fix your html:

```
<button id="change">Change</button>
<div>
    <div class="box"> 
        <p class="hello">Hello, this is text1</p>
        <p class="goodbye">Goodbye, this is text1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p class="hello">Hello, this is text2</p>
        <p class="goodbye">Goodbye, this is text2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery becomes:

```
$('.goodbye').hide();

$('#change').click(function () {
    $('.hello').fadeOut(200, function () {
        $('.goodbye').fadeIn(600);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p4sA3/6/)